# Oracle says not a group by expresssion

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to Oracle.

I tried a query in `MySQL` and it works fine

```
select 
    segment1, description, organization_id
from
    apps.mtl_system_items_b
where
    organization_id IN (110 , 268, 448)
GROUP BY segment1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT organization_id) = 3
```

But in `Oracle`, it says `not a group by expression`.  What's wrong?

EDIT:-

I want the result like this

```
organisation_id   segment1
110               306145244
268               306145244
448               306145244
110               444444444
268               444444444
448               444444444
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have ungrouped an unaggregated expressions in your `SELECT` list.

`MySQL` allows them (without specifying which of many possible values will it return), but `Oracle` does not.

By definition, your query will return only segments with 3 different organizations. So which of those organizations you want to return?

If you only want to return segment, just use this:

```
SELECT  segment1
FROM    apps.mtl_system_items_b
WHERE   organization_id IN (110 , 268, 448)
GROUP BY
        segment1
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT organization_id) = 3
```

If you want all items with segments belonging to three organizations, use this:

```
SELECT  segment1, description, organization_id
FROM    (
        SELECT  i.*,
                COUNT(DISTINCT organization_id) OVER (PARTITION BY segment1) cnt
        FROM    apps.mtl_system_items_b
        WHERE   organization_id IN (110, 268, 448)
        )
WHERE   cnt = 3
```

Comment: I want segments which are having all 3 organization. Please gimme that query also.

Comment: If segment is under 2 organization or one organization I don't want that segment .... And in the return result I want all the 3 rows also

Comment: I want all 3 ..segment1, description, organization_id

Comment: @Sahal: which `organization_id`? You have three of them. Please post some sample data and desired output.

Comment: I want like this.... If the segment is there in all the 3 organisation (110 , 268, 448) I wig get 3 rows for one segment.

Comment: Second query , you used COUNT so GROUP BY is not required ?

Comment: @Sahal: no, it's not. It's a window function, not aggregate. See `PARTITION BY` though.

Comment: But in this case I am getting one row. Not 3 rows

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the quick answer

```
select 
segment1, description, organization_id from
apps.mtl_system_items_b where
organization_id IN (110 , 268, 448) 
GROUP BY segment1, description, organization_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT organization_id) =3
```

Maybe this explanation could help you to gain some understanding in terms of GROUP BY

The SQL GROUP BY clause can be used in an SQL SELECT statement to collect data across multiple records and group the results by one or more columns.

The syntax for the SQL GROUP BY clause is:

```
SELECT column1, column2, ... column_n, aggregate_function (expression)
FROM tables
WHERE predicates
GROUP BY column1, column2, ... column_n;
```

aggregate_function can be a function such as SQL SUM function, SQL COUNT function, SQL MIN function, or SQL MAX function.

Since you have the aggregate_function you need to group by each of the field you display or select.

Please refer to the depth-explanation below

> http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj32654.html

Comment: Please take the time to explain why this is a good answer. You might know, but the OP won't learn unless you explain.

Comment: This query will never return anything. How can `COUNT(DISTINCT organization_id)` be equal to `3` if you group by `organization_id`?

Comment: You might post the answer regarding your option @Quassnoi rather than correcting other people's answer. Just be wise and help :)

Comment: Thank you @theTinMan , I already explained the simple explanation though the explanation was simple and short

Comment: @javalovers: I did not correct your answer, I just said it will not return anything. BTW the downvote is not mine.

Comment: Hahahaha never mind,I don't care when people downvoting others, just wanted to help, regarding al people who downvote or whatsoever I don't care that's only score which means nothing than number hahaha...

Comment: @javalovers: sure, but just making the query compile without really understanding what the user wants is hardly useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the reason why the query work on MySQL: [MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html).

In `Oracle` and any other RDBMS, this won't work because you need to explicitly list all the non-aggregated columns on the group by clause. To make it work, add them on the `GROUP BY` clause

```
GROUP BY segment1, description, organization_id
```